# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript

Buenas estoy comenzando hacer validaciones con js y me esta saliendo este error,

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

```
const formulario = document.getElementById('formulario')
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#formulario input')

formulario.addEventListener('submit',(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Podrías pasar el HTML para ver el código completo e identificar el error? Gracias.

Comment: El error que indicas es literalmente porque no existe un elemento con id 'formulario'. Comprueba que esté bien escrito en tu html y utiliza el botón [edit] para añadir el HTML relativo a tu pregunta, por favor. Recuerda que debes proporcionar un [mre] para que podamos ayudarte!